# Ruby on Rails - Re-Rendering a form on a failed controller action with the original parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller that looks like the following:

```
def update
  @expense_report = ExpenseReport.find(params[:id])
  @expense_report.status = "Submitted"

  respond_to do |format|
    if @expense_report.update(expense_report_params)
      ...
      ...
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      ...
    end
  end 
end
```

I am attempting to set the status before the update, so I can reduce the number of saves performed. I'd prefer only one save to occur. However, when the form is re-rendered on a failed save, it is re-rendered with the original parameters AND the status set to Submitted, even though 'Submitted' was not one of the original params. Is there a way to render with only the original parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@artur.prado is on the right track with [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61269497/3982562), but is missing re-assigning the user provided parameters. I've made this into a separate answer, because changing his answer would completely overhaul what he has written and might go against his intent.

You can restore the database version with [`restore_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-restore_attributes), then re-apply the submitted changes with [`assign_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes).

```
def update
  @expense_report = ExpenseReport.find(params[:id])
  @expense_report.status = "Submitted"

  respond_to do |format|
    if @expense_report.update(expense_report_params)
      # ...
    else
      @expense_report.restore_attributes
      @expense_report.assign_attributes(expense_report_params)

      format.html { render :edit }
      # ...
    end
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.2 introduced exactly what you need. On the `else` block, just call

```
@expense_report.restore_attributes
```

before rendering the view. It will do the trick.